# detect error during Bone Heat Weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones

Tags: python, weight-painting

I am using the operator `bpy.ops.paint.weight_from_bones` to generate weight maps from within Python. This works great as long as the weighting algorithm in Blender does not get stuck. But sometimes the operator terminates with a warning message in the Console saying:

```
Bone Heat Weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones
```

However, the operator returns {'FINISHED'} and there is no apparent trace of the warning seen within Python.

So is there any way to check from within Python if the operator missed to generate weights for some bones? And even better, can i get some information about which bones failed or which vertices where affected...

This information would make it possible to visualize where the generator could not find a solution.